Why am I measuring 1e6 ohm forward resistance on a functioning LED?
I have an LED board with a busted driver, so I thought I'd probe the LEDs to determine a good replacement driver. If I probe the LEDs I don't get a readout on the voltage drop but the LEDs light up fine on the probe current. What's more, if I measure the LED forward resistance it's about 1M ohm for the red LEDs and >2M ohm for the white LEDs.
I verified the direction of the LEDs, and my probe reads a resistance of about 0.1 ohm if I short the probe needles.
I am failing to understand what is going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated!
The board configuration is 9 parallel groups of 25 LEDs and a single 0.2 ohm resistor, disconnected from the old driver.

The resistor doesn't help work anything out. Depending on the number of connections between the two sections, it could be used for measuring current. It could even be a cheap fuse (there are resistors with a specified action energy, so it is possible.) One thing such a resistor does not do is distribute the current evenly in all 9 strings. And so they must be depending on the fact that by the time 25 LEDs are added to a string that the probabilities argue that the distribution of currents will be sufficiently even, whatever that means. More info is needed to help with the driver.

I guess it doesn't really matter, working out why you get the measurements you are getting. I gather the LEDs are fine. So your problem appears to be the driver replacement, as you also write. So you should get on with that business and forget about learning how multimeters work, since that's not going to help in replacing the driver section. So I take it what you really need to know, is the process you might use -- observations and measurements and photos, etc -- to work out how to replace the driver with a result that works and is safe to use.

The "resistance" of the LED is non-linear and depends entirely on operating current (and temperature to a much lesser degree). More specifically, you are inadvertently measuring "slope resistance", but not really, because you don't know what the DMM test current is.
Some theory: When the DMM (multimeter) is put in resistance mode, it outputs a constant current at the leads. When a resistive element is placed across the leads, the DMM detects the voltage dropped across the element and displays the ratio of voltage dropped to test current as resistance (Ohm's Law). This works fine when you have a resistor as the DUT because resistors have linear relationship between applied volage and current, and a constant "slope resistance". This is what the meter was designed to measure in this mode.
Now the treatment for your case: the LED. The LED is a PN junction (a diode) and it does not obey Ohm's Law. In other word's, the current follows a characteristic curve vs voltage such that at low voltages (<Vf) very little current flows (10's of uA typ.). Near Vf (forward voltage drop, the "knee" voltage that you find in the spec sheet), the current shoots up exponentially. Past Vf, the current will be in a regime where the LED will overheat and self-destruct as it can no longer limit the current. This is why it needs current-limiting series resistor. Or a fancy constant-current source or sink.
The DMM has no idea there is an LED there, so depending on the test current, the voltage dropped at the current gives the "resistance" the meter displays.
It's worth mentioning that if you try to measure the resistance of a largish capacitor in this mode, the meter will display increasing updates of resistance (depending on meter sample/refresh rate) until the "resistance" measurement gets so high it is out of range and displays "O.L" of something similar that indicates open-circuit; the capacitor is now "charged" from the DMM test current and it no longer has enough compliance voltage to charge it further. From the standpoint of the meter, it's an open circuit.
One other point when measuring non-linear resistances with typical DMMs is that if they have auto-ranging, depending on the DUT and the operating point, the meter could "hunt" for the proper range and never settle. This is when you have to use manual mode.

Just a note and not a complaint: The question doesn't specifically state the use of a DMM. So it may be an analog meter.

@periblepsis True. That was an assumption on my part but the principles are the same regardless of meter type. Sure, different meters may use different test currents and the meter to meter measurements will read differently do to a difference in operating point.

There's a bit of a difference between how they each measure. Have a look here for the behavioral schematic when measuring resistance with an analog meter. It's not quite the same method as used by DMMs. But I'm not asking for an argument. Just making a note that the question didn't say, one way or another, but that you used a specific term that excludes analog meters. That's all.

You don't say what you are using to probe the LEDs, but it does not matter.
LEDs are not resistors, so a device that measures current and voltage of the probes and computes you a reading in ohms can't give you a valid reading in ohms for a LED as the probed item is assumed to be a resistor. The meter simply gives you a reading what resistor it would equal with the given test voltage and test current.
Different colour LEDs have different voltage drops over them, so as white LEDs have a forward voltage much higher than red LED, it explains the difference in your measurements.
So, measuring LEDs in resistance mode does not give a sensible reading.
Measuring LEDs in diode voltage drop may also not provide sensible results, as the meter may not be intended for measuring the high voltage drops of white LEDs. Usually you will be measuring voltage drops of standard diodes, such as schottky, silicon, germanium, etc, which have smalle voltage drops.
You need to refer to the manual of your meter to know under what limitations it can be used to measure things in different modes.
For example the continuity test of some meters do not really test continuity, but if the measured resistance is below some arbitrary threshold, which is why given say a 100 ohm resistor, some meters indicate continuity and some don't.
